# ProcessDrag in Standalone Input Module doesn't work as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to emulate a user actions from code, like clicking an dragging and have decided to use the StandaloneInputModule. Method *ProcessTouchPress* with the right PointerEventData works as intended. When I am trying to emulate dragging of an user, there are some problems: 
This is my IEnumerator I use for dragging.

```
IEnumerator SimulateDrag(Vector2 from, Vector2 to, float dur) 
{
    Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = true;
    float startTime = Time.time;
    float endTime = Time.time + dur;
    PointerEventData data = null;
    float t = 0f;
    while(t < 1) {

        t = Mathf.InverseLerp(startTime, endTime, Time.time);
        // Debug.Log(t);
        Vector2 pos  = Vector2.Lerp(from, to, t);
        data = GeneratePointerData(pos);
        ProcessDrag(data);
        yield return null;
    }
    
}
```

The *GeneratePointerData* method just simply returns *PointerEventData* with current position:

```
PointerEventData GeneratePointerData(Vector2 pos) 
{
    var data = GetTouchPointerEventData(new Touch() 
    {
        position = pos,
        
    }, out bool b, out bool bb);

    ExecuteEvents.Execute(data.pointerDrag, data, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
    data.dragging = true;
    
    return data;
}
```

I should also mention that this app is going to be used in mobile phones, therefore the *dragging with finger*.

I have also tried rewriting the ProcessDrag method myself and executing the events this way:

```
ExecuteEvents.Execute(data.pointerDrag, data, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
```

ProcessTouchPress works just fine:

```
void PressScreen(Vector2 pos, bool pressed, bool released) 
{
    Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = true;
    var pointerData = GeneratePointerData(pos);
    ProcessTouchPress(pointerData, pressed, released);
}
```

I have spent many hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, so any feedback/help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this question is year old, but maybe someone will face this issue as I did. Anyway I've managed to solve this issue by invoking following methods:

1. `ProcessTouchPress(startEventData, true, false);`
2. Looped `ProcessDrag(dragEventData);`
3. Once loop is done: `ProcessTouchPress(endEventData, false, true);`

Also, you need to modify your `GeneratePointerData` method to also set `phase` and `rawPosition`. Otherwise swipe isn't working as expected. So to conclude your code should look like this:

```
PointerEventData GeneratePointerData(Vector2 pos, TouchPhase phase) 
{
    var data = GetTouchPointerEventData(new Touch() 
    {
        position = pos, phase = phase, rawPosition = pos
        
    }, out bool b, out bool bb); 
    return data;
}

IEnumerator SimulateDrag(Vector2 from, Vector2 to, float dur) 
{
    Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = true;
    float startTime = Time.time;
    float endTime = Time.time + dur;
    ProcessTouchPress(GeneratePointerData(from, TouchPhase.Began), true, false);
    float t = 0f;
    while(t < 1) {
        t = Mathf.InverseLerp(startTime, endTime, Time.time);
        // Debug.Log(t);
        Vector2 pos  = Vector2.Lerp(from, to, t);
        ProcessDrag(GeneratePointerData(pos, TouchPhase.Moved));
        yield return null;
    }
    ProcessTouchPress(GeneratePointerData(to, TouchPhase.Ended), false, true);
}
```